# unable to access my website from external devices using XAMPP

Tags: xampp, ip-address, web-hosting, portforwarding

I am trying to host my first website using xampp server. I can't seem to make it work. With my WAN IP, I can access my website from my pc where the router is located (LAN) but I cannot access my website from other external sources with different network.

I have configured xampp and had port forwarding with my router correctly. I also had made a rule in my firewall enabling incoming port 80 and allowed apps "Apache HTTP Server" both private and public. but the results are still the same

What should I do to access my website from other external devices?